# Hiding and showing Navigator for different scenes

Tags: react-native

I'd like to, in my router on `renderScene`, be able to have a property of scenes/components etc. to hide the Navigator bar.

Unfortunately, I can't modify the state of the navigationbar, and have a re-render fire with conditions.  I guess that's because of the way it's set?

```
export default class Root extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={Routes.SubdomainScreen}
        renderScene={Router.renderScene}
        configureScene={Router.configureScene}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
          />
        }
        style={styles.container}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Ideally, in my router, some components with have navigationbar set to false, and I will then update the style of the navigator to `{opacity:0}`.   When/where would someone accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your route definitions and add a `hideNavBar` property to it, then track it with state.

```
export default class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hideNavBar: false,
    };
  }

  render(){
    let navBar = null;

    if (! this.state.hideNavBar) {
      navBar = (
        <Navigator.NavigationBar
          routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={Routes.SubdomainScreen}
        renderScene={Router.renderScene}
        configureScene={Router.configureScene}
        onWillFocus={this.onNavWillFocus.bind(this)}
        navigationBar={navBar}
        style={styles.container}
      />
    )
  }
  onNavWillFocus(route) {
    if (route.hideNavBar !== undefined && this.state.hideNavBar !== route.hideNavBar) {
      this.setState({hideNavBar: route.hideNavBar});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I switched my onNavWillFocus to this one line:
`this.setState({hideNavBar: !!route.hideNavBar})` Both work great!